# Is it mandatory to override servlet init() or init(ServletConfig config) and destroy() methods

Tags: servlets, init, destroy

Can you please tell me that, is it mandatory to override init() or init(ServletConfig config) and destroy() methods in the new servlet (ex:HelloServlet) which we write?

Answer (score 0):

These two methods are a part of the `javax.servlet.Servlet` interface; so, they must somehow be implemented, either by your servlet or by a base class of your servlet.

Usually, you'd write a servlet that does not directly implement `javax.servlet.Servlet`, but extend the `javax.servlet.GenericServlet` class or the `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` class. If you extend either of these, then you don't have to override `init` or `destroy` - as long as the superclass' implementation is OK with you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I thought the same but was not sure.. It is clarified now.